# How can I create a customize LicensePage by using LicenseRegistry

Tags: flutter

I want to customize the License data by using LicenseRegistry. But I don't know how to
use it.
here is my code. what should I do if I want to make all of the packages and content in one page.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<LicenseEntry>(
      // API
        stream: LicenseRegistry.licenses,

        builder: (_, snapshot) {

          return Container(
            // how to get the data
          );
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is open source so you can see how the `showLicensePage()` implement the display of the Packages.

What you are looking for is in this file, line 581 : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/b400534dc763b5e5f020e76f0eee23b3295453e9/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/about.dart